# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 4

Tags: r, pandoc

I am trying to produce a pdf from a Rmd file.
I am using Rstudio 2021.09.0 with R 4.1.1 and rmarkdown 2.10.
When I try to `rmarkdown::render(input = "Intro.Rmd",output_file ="Intro.pdf")` I get this error:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Intro.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Intro.pdf --lua-filter "D:\ONEDRI~3\RStudio\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\PAGEBR~1.LUA" --lua-filter "D:\ONEDRI~3\RStudio\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\LATEX-~1.LUA" --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --standalone --section-divs --template "D:\ONEDRI~3\RStudio\RMARKD~1\rmd\h\DEFAUL~1.HTM" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --include-in-header "C:\Users\jpmar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcJegHW\rmarkdown-str54ec9513115.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" 
cannot produce pdf output from html4
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 4
```

Any idea on how to solve this? I can't find any information on error 4.

Thanks!
João

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install tinytex()... MikeTex (Windows) does not fully work.

Comment: Hi @JPMD, How do I use `tinytex()`?  It was installed.

Comment: When you install tinytex with ```install.packages("tinytex", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")``` and  ```tinytex::install_tinytex()```it should be the default tex installer. If not, and if you are using RStudio go to TOOLS > GLOBAL OPTIONS > SWEAVE and check "Use TinyTex when compiling .tex files".